# how to get a variable from require 'db.php' file inside a function?

Tags: php

when I run this page ,it says: `Undefined variable: db` how can I use the $db from db.php inside the validate() function ?

```
<?php

    require_once 'global.php';
    require 'db.php';

    function validate($user,$pass) {

        $users=array();

        $result=$db->query('SELECT username,password FROM users');

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using global keyword is bad practice. Instead pass the database variable as a parameter.

```
function validate($db) {

}
```

And since you are using a class,  you can take advantage of object oriented programming features. Meaning you only have to initialize the database connection once though the construct function

```
class myDb {

var $db; 
function __construct($db){
  $this->db = $db
}

function validate(){
//you can access database using $this->db
$result=$this->db->query('SELECT username,password FROM users');
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the global variable scope inside your function:

```
<?php
    require_once 'global.php';
    require 'db.php';

    function validate($user,$pass) {
        global $db;

        $users=array();

        $result=$db->query('SELECT username,password FROM users');

        ...
    }
```

Check out the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php